# Sending email functionality is not working for site guest user of org

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, apex-email-service, guest-user

We have one visualforce page which is working fine previously for sending emails but now it is not working.
All other functions from that visualforce page are working fine But send mail functionality is not working which worked previously.
For the admin user, it is working fine if we preview the visualforce page from the developer console. It is not working only for guest users. Also checked the profile and site setting but did not find anything.

For sending mail code is given below:-

```
Messaging.singleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.singleEmailMessage();
List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
sendTo.add(con.Email);
mail.setToAddresses(sendTo);
mail.setReplyTo('info@twopirconsulting.com');
mail.setSenderDisplayName('twopir consulting');
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
mail.setSubject('Token for Employee Portal Login');
String body = '<html><body>Dear ' + contactList[0].Name + ',<br><br>Use Token : ' +systemToken+' to log into Employee Portal</body></html>';
            
mail.setHtmlBody(body);
mails.add(mail);
Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
```

Can you please help us for solving the issue?

Comment: what does "not working" mean?, `Messaging.sendEmail` returns `Messaging.SendEmailResult` which could be inspected

Comment: @cropredy Not working means the mail is not getting sent to the user.  And in debug, SendEmailResult method isSuccess returns true

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your Guest User has a valid email assigned.

This is discussed in the article listed [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000362827&type=1).

Comment: Yes, we have assigned a valid email address to the guest user.

Comment: To anyone looking around for a solution, this seems to be the key step to take to make this work. I did not have to have "Send Email" on the profile. Setting an Org Wide Email address did **not** work.

Comment: Nice... It seems particularly relevant for sandboxes where user email addresses are all invalid by default

Answer (score 0):

Do the users have the relevant Apex class in their profile or PermissionSet?
Do you get an error message logged?

Comment: Yes, we have assigned apex classes and all permissions. No, we don't get any error messages. Only the mail is not sent to users.

Answer (score 0):

You can set organization-Wide Addresses and use them when you want to send the email.

Docuement: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_default_no_reply.htm&type=5

Example: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setOrgWideEmailAddressId

Please try as suggested, it should work